# Move the button with textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

Probably thi is a simple question. But I'm new with css and javascript.
I have a button below the textarea and I want the button to move along with the textarea when I extend it!
How can I do this?

Comment: Show code and jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align button to textarea corner and keep it in same relative position while expand contract, try the following :

First of all, the HTML code :

```
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <p>
        <input type="reset"/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Then, add css property :

```
form {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

form textarea {
    min-width: 140px;
}

form p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Finally, here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDxc5/12/).

Enjoy your day!